# Intl "timezone is not supported" react native

Tags: react-native, timezone

The following code gives me the following error:

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", { timeZone: 'America/New_York' }).format()
```

> RangeError: timeZone is not supported

How can I fix this? The issue is on Android

Answer (score 0):

Try use this fix https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/1377#issuecomment-1191900686

```
import '@formatjs/intl-getcanonicallocales/polyfill';
import '@formatjs/intl-locale/polyfill';

import '@formatjs/intl-displaynames/polyfill';
import '@formatjs/intl-displaynames/locale-data/en'; // locale-data for en

import '@formatjs/intl-listformat/polyfill';
import '@formatjs/intl-listformat/locale-data/en'; // locale-data for en

import '@formatjs/intl-pluralrules/polyfill';
import '@formatjs/intl-pluralrules/locale-data/en'; // locale-data for en

import '@formatjs/intl-numberformat/polyfill';
import '@formatjs/intl-numberformat/locale-data/en'; // locale-data for en

import '@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/polyfill';
import '@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/locale-data/en'; // locale-data for en

import '@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/polyfill';
import '@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/locale-data/en'; // locale-data for en
import '@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/add-all-tz'; // Add ALL tz data

// @ts-ignore
Date.prototype._toLocaleString = Date.prototype.toLocaleString;
Date.prototype.toLocaleString = function (a, b) {
  if (b && Object.keys(b).length === 1 && 'timeZone' in b && a === 'en-US') {
    return Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-us', {
      year: 'numeric',
      month: '2-digit',
      day: '2-digit',
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit',
      second: '2-digit',
      hour12: false,
      timeZone: b.timeZone,
    })
      .format(this)
      .replace(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}),/g, '$3-$1-$2');
  }
  // @ts-ignore
  return this._toLocaleString(a, b);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible that you enabled Hermes if that's the case try using Moment or date-fns

Comment: It is not helpful because Hermes does not full support Intl https://github.com/facebook/hermes/issues/23 and these libraries did not help (under the hood React Native use Intl)